# What happens if an exception is raised in constructor

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens to base class destructor if a derived class destructor throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508533/what-happens-to-base-class-destructor-if-a-derived-class-destructor-throws-an-exc)

If I throw an exception in the constructor of a derived class, is the destructor called to clean up the base class?

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple test-program to check?

Comment: No. I was thinking that some discussion may happen here. And i will learn more then if i make test.

Answer (score 11):

The destructors of the base class(es) are then called in the reverse order.

Before that, the destructors of any already initialized member will also get called.

However, the destructor of the currently constructed derived-class won't get called, as this part of the object will not have been really constructed yet.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. For example, consider:

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
public:
    B() { std::cout << "B()\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()\n"; }
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    D() { std::cout << "D()\n"; throw 23; }
    ~D() { std::cout << "~D()\n"; }
};

int main()
try
{
    D d;
    return 0;
}
catch(...) {}
```

Output:

```
B()
D()
~B()
```

Answer (score 7):

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10

> Every data member inside your object should clean up its own mess.
>
> If a constructor  throws an exception, the object's destructor is not
>   run.   If your object has already done something  that needs  to be
>   undone  (such   as allocating some memory,  opening a file, or locking
>   a semaphore),  this   "stuff that needs to be undone" must be
>   remembered by a data member inside the object.

Base destructors are guaranteed to be called, but not the destructor of the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Once construction of a base or member sub-object is complete, that sub-object will be properly destroyed if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, throwing an exception in the constructor is one of the COMMON ways to detect object construction failure as long as it's properly handled by the caller, as there is NO return value of constructor.